# Memory leak using window.eval() in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, memory-leaks, microsoft-edge

I have a simple test case where I call the `window.evaluate` function.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        function test() {
            // do something important
        }   
        setInterval(
            function() {
                window.eval("test();");
            }, 
            100
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I open this page within Firefox, Chrome and Edge and profile the memory, I can see different results. Note that I'm using Windows 10 Pro 64b.

```
         at start      after cca 9 hours   browser version
         -------------------------------------------------
Edge:    0.28MB        0.28MB              38.14393.0.0
Chrome:  1.70MB        1.90MB              53.0.2785.116
Firefox: 0.25MB        115.3MB             49.0.1
```

There is a huge heap size growth in Firefox - **from 0.25 MB to 115MB**.

As @charlietfl mention in a comment below this question I also did the same test without the `window.eval` function. So I just call `test()` within the interval callback.

```
         at start      after cca 9 hours   browser version
         -------------------------------------------------
Edge:    0.27MB        0.27MB              38.14393.0.0
Chrome:  1.60MB        1.60MB              53.0.2785.116
Firefox: 0.19MB        0.19MB              49.0.1
```

As you can see, any heap size didn't change at all.

So I'm asking if this testing javascript code is wrong on its own or the Firefox is buggy when using the `window.evaluate` function.

Comment: Did you benchmark this against calling the function without eval?

Comment: That different browsers use different amounts of memory when running internal functions comes as no suprise at all? Remember that eval is evil, and generally should be avoided.

Comment: @charlietfl yes I did, check my updated question

Comment: I can confirm this, and it's not just in an interval.. calling eval from a button click or other method produces the same results of a memory leak. This is not true of older firefox versions so it's definitely a new bug.  @adeneo eval is not evil, it is just generally misused.

Answer (score 0):

So yes, the memory leak in 49.0.1 exists.  An Alternative method that should work without the memory issues is Function.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        function test() {
            console.log("running test");
        }   
        setInterval(
            function() {
                 (new Function( 'return ' + 'test()' ) )();
            }, 
            100
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is an very old bug that seems to have very similar symptoms
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=468791