# new Function(...).call() creates a memory leak in chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, memory-leaks

```
function test() {
}    


for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i ++) {
    (new Function(`with(this) { return ${  test  }}`)).call({ hello: 'world' });    
}
```

And the live code I am actually triyng to debug is

```
  const ret = (new Function(`with(this) { return ${$eval}}`))
               .call({ moment, ...context });
```

This creates a memory leak and so does eval ( ie `eval("test();");` in the for loop ).

I don't know how to work around this and I would expect it to not leak memory considering this answer: [Memory leak using window.eval() in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773622/memory-leak-using-window-eval-in-firefox)

Comment: What is your use case? What would you like to achieve?

Comment: evaluate code in a JSON file! @IterAtor